# GridView ImageButton confirm and delete record

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I've got a huge problem here. I've managed to add javascript to my server side, but the problem it is not deleting. It doesnt have produce any errors so I don't know where to start:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand
    If e.CommandName = "cmdDelete" Then
        Dim ID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
    End If
End Sub
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim l As ImageButton = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("ImageDelete"), ImageButton)
        l.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return " & "confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record " & DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ID") & "')")
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_RowDeleting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDeleting
    Dim ID As Integer = CInt(GridView1.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Value)
    'dim ID as Integer
    con.Open()
    'gridview1.rows(e.rowindex).cells(0)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("delete from  [tblUser] where [ID]=@ID", con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Client side

```
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
  <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageDelete" ImageUrl="" runat="server" CommandName="cmdDelete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'
    />
  </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns
```

Comment: are you seeing the javascript confirm message? And when you press yes/ok does it raise RowCommand event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown in your markup whether you're adding ID as a datakey to the GridView.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" ...>
```

And I think you might have a problem with the way you're retrieving the ID in the delete logic:

```
Dim ID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys(e.RowIndex)("ID"))
```

Answer (score 2):

When the `ImageDelete` button is pressed, `RowCommand` event occurs. However, in the event handler for `RowCommand` you are not deleting anything. On the other hand `RowDeleting` event won't occur at all, since the correct command for this event is `Delete`, not `cmdDelete`.

I see two possible fixes for this. First - move your code for delete operation to the `RowCommand` event handler:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand
    If e.CommandName = "cmdDelete" Then
        Dim ID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)

        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("delete from  [tblUser] where [ID]=@ID", con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()

    End If
End Sub
```

Second - change the command name and use your already implemented `RowDeleting` handler:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageDelete" ImageUrl="" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
```

Comment: sir what i did is add <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" /> on client side and now it works

Comment: @Janwel, Actually another possible fix for the problem I've described. Delete button in `CommandField` simply sends `Delete` command to the server, causing `RowDeleting` event to occur. That's why it works.